# Delete row using UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have built a simple `UserForm` with a `Combobox` to delete rows by name.

- I have populated the `Combobox` rowsource using a macro to build a
  named range called "Combo_List". I statically inserted that into the
  rowsource attribute (meaning, I did not do that with code).
- Also on the `UserForm` is a `Checkbox` that I want to use for *confirmation* purposes.
- Once they select the username from the list, they need to put a check in the `Checkbox` and THEN they can click the Delete button.

I have no clue how to write the code that validates the `Checkbox` and then deletes the selected row.

If it helps, here's the code to build the named range and then show the `UserForm`:

```
Sub RecordDelete()

Dim LastRow As Long
ActiveSheet.Select

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 
Range("B3:B" & LastRow).Name = "Combo_List" 
frmDeleteData.Show

End Sub
```

The checkbox is just named 'checkbox1'. Any help?

Comment: Seeing your file (santised if needs be) would make this much easier ......

Comment: I've never used DropBox before, so let me know if you don't get the file. Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bs3qlszorecdoh/Delete_Demo.xlsm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is

1. Set the default property for `Enabled` for your delete `CommandButton` to `False` in design mode
2. Add code to the `CheckBox` that enables the `CommandButton`when the `Checkbox` is ticked
3. Add code to the delete `CommandButton` to delete the entire row

**code**

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 CommandButton1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    If Me.CheckBox1 Then
        Set rng1 = Range("Combo_List").Find(Me.ComboBox1.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            rng1.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            MsgBox Me.ComboBox1.Value & "not found"
        End If
    Else
    `redundant if button is disabled
        MsgBox "Checkbox not checked!", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```